# Word meaning "being tossed up and down?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to replace the phrase "being tossed up and down." To be used in something like:

> The tree trunk [...] between the waves.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In seas or oceans, the word "[bob](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bob)" is often used to describe the up and down motion:

> the boat bobbed up and down

If you need something a bit more severe-sounding you could go with something like:

- Crashed
- Flipped
- Tumbled

Comment: +1 *The tree trunk **bobbed over** the waves.* None of the other alternatives work.

Comment: @Kris: _Crashed, flipped,_ and _tumbled_ could work, if the weather was rough, the seas heavy, and the tree trunk near the shore. I've stood on the beach in such weather, and objects don't _bob_ up and down. They crash, flip, and tumble in the surf.

Comment: @J.R. But 'up and down' is what the OP wanted and that was both realistic and reasonable. And Oh, yes, things do 'bob up and down' on the surface. Above all, *bob* is the only word that inherently means an 'up and down' movement, which is what I wanted to say in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Another term which fits very nicely in the context of waves is *buffet*:

> v. buf·fet·ed, buf·fet·ing, buf·fets v.tr.
>
> 1. To hit or beat, especially repeatedly.
> 2. To strike against forcefully; batter: winds that buffeted the tent.
> 3. To drive or force with or as if with repeated blows: was buffeted about from job to job by the vagaries of the economy.
> 4. To force (one's way) with difficulty.

For example:

> The tree trunk was buffeted by the waves.

*Buffet*, however, implies violence, it is not a gentle rise and fall with the swell. You would use it for a floating object caught in a storm and not in calm seas. If you are looking for something calm you can use *bob*, as suggested by @Ste, which means simply floating and gently rising and falling with the motion of the water.

If you are looking for something intermediate, neither battered (which can also be used instead of *bufetted*), nor calmly *bobbing*, go for *jostled* as suggested by @TecBrat.

Comment: I also see buffet as hitting something repeatedly. Bobbed is a better choice since the item can bob more or less by itself

Comment: @mplungjan yes, I just wasn't sure whether the OP was looking for a word that conveys calm or violence. A tree trunk would not really bob in a storm, it would be buffeted by the waves.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the word "jostled". One can say "The tree trunk jostled in the waves." or "The tree trunk was jostled by the waves".

Answer (score 1):

Try **[bounce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bounce)**

> (*v.i.*) to rebound or reflect after striking a surface (such as the
>   ground or the wave); to leap suddenly

*The tree trunk **bounced** between the waves.*

Answer (score 0):

For a tree trunk moving up and down on a wave of water, the word *undulate* is the literal answer. It means to move in a smooth, wave-like fashion.